Python Requests: website does not recognize login after returning status <200>
I'm trying to scrape letterboxd.com for film info, but when I try to fetch the HTML of the page I'd like to use, I was getting served different HTML than my browser. So, I tried to log in through a requests Session. But even after getting a <200> status from the response, any GET I perform on the page does not recognize my credentials (nor does this change the HTML I get served).
I've verified that my User-Agent header is the same my browser gives (all the rest of the headers are requests defaults), as well looking at the HTML to make sure I'm giving all required information. I must be missing something. Here is the HTML of the <form> section of the website:


<form method="post" action="#" id="signin" class="signin signin-form js-header-signin-form js-signin" data-url="/user/login.do" data-recaptcha-action="signin" novalidate='novalidate' autocorrect='off' autocapitalize='off'>
    <input type="hidden" name="__csrf" value="placeholder" />
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticationCode" value="" />
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <div class="fields">
            <div class="col">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="email" name="username" id="username" class="field signin-field" tabindex="1" data-focus-control="signingIn" autocomplete='email' inputmode='email' value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="field signin-field" tabindex="2" autocomplete='current-password' value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="signin-actions">
                <label for="remember" class="option-label -checkbox -small">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" class="checkbox" tabindex="3" value="true" /><i class="substitute"></i>
                    <span class="focus">Remember<span class="mob-hide"> me</span></span>
                </label>
                <p class="reset" tabindex="5"><a class="reset-password-link" href="/user/request-password-reset" target="_top">Forgotten<span class="elongated"> username or password</span>?</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col buttons">
                <div class="button-container"><input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="button -action button-green" tabindex="4" /><i></i></div>
                <div class="close js-close-signin">&times;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="signin-message" class="errormessage"></div>
</form>



From this, I tried to find the relevant data to POST, and wrote the following code:
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"    # from browser

login = {'__csrf': 'a0b859246d2044858517',     # from Chrome Inspector, after login
         'authenticationCode': '',             # this was left null in browser
         'username': 'my_user',                # from name='username' in an <input> element
         'password': 'my_pass',                # from name='password'
         'remember': 'true',                   # from name='remember'
         'submit':   'Sign In'}                # from type='submit'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = user_agent

    p = s.post("https://letterboxd.com/user/login.do",   # from data-url member in <form> element
               data=login,
               auth=('my_user', 'my_pass'))

    print(p.status_code)

The output of this code is 200. Yet, when I GET the homepage, within the same session, a JS script in the response HTML indicates that I am not logged in, notably in this line:
analytic_params['user_type'] = 'Visitor';

This goes unchanged after the requests login. In my browser this line reads as follows after login:
analytic_params['user_type'] = 'Member';

I must be missing some authentication, or something simple. I'm quite new at this, so insight would be helpful!

is the data that you're trying to scrape only available to registered users?

@GTK It's not, which is what's odd to me. The specific page I'm trying to scrape is this one, which you can clearly see without an account: https://letterboxd.com/films/popular/page/1/ Logging in was something I thought I could try so I could actually get the same HTML as my browser. Maybe there's a simpler way?

since the data is available without an account, there is no need to login, edit your question with exact data you want? is it simply the names of the movies? or more?

See, that's what I tried first, but the response did not give me the same HTML as I see in my browser's inspector, even after using my browser's User-Agent string. This different HTML does not contain any film information. This is my problem.

The site uses ajax to load the data, you can get it from https://letterboxd.com/films/ajax/popular/page/1, but it only has minimal information about the movie, you might need to make extra requests if you need details.

Huh, that fixed it! That actually gives me all the info I need. Good catch; I didn't realize it would route through a slightly different URL.

The answer, given by user GTK, is that Letterboxd uses Ajax to load its data, which changes the URL from what's in the browser. The issue was not login credentials (perhaps unsurprisingly). All that's needed to get film information from my target, https://letterboxd.com/films/popular/page/1 (albeit minimal) is use the following URL: https://letterboxd.com/films/ajax/popular/page/1 (/ajax/ is all that was added). This only gives images, titles, and links to individual film pages, but that's enough to get all the rest of the info you could want.
